# Dynamic reports classnotfoundexception

Tags: java, exe, dynamic-reports

I have a java program that uses dynamic reports fine in netbeans, and even works in exe and jar when I first run it. However, if I share the jar/exe (I've even sent it and re-downloaded it on my own computer), I get an error `java.lang.classnotfoundexception: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.jrdatasource`. However, I have double checked my jars and I do have this class. What could be the source of this problem then?

[image]

Thanks

Edit: full error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRDataSource
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 7 more
```

Answer (score 0):

if you  get `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:` inside a jar file  then, you need to provide the classpath arguments;
example:

```
java -cp my.jar -jar ExternalJarFileName.jar
```

you can also provide all jars use below command, only need to create a directory and put all external jars in to it and use path of directory in to below command:

```
java -cp my.jar;C:\externalJar\* mainpackage.MainClass
```

Comment: Is this supposed to go in my code? Or do I put it in the command prompt? Also, my.jar is the jar for my program and externaljarfilename is the jar that the class wasn't found in, right? Sorry, I'm a bit new at this.

Comment: I added the following to my code but it still doesn't work:
 `     
     `try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr = rt.exec("java -cp project.jar -jar jasperreports-6.4.0.jar");
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }`
`
Is this not what I was supposed to do or is something else wrong?